# array_search result not getting properly

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter-3

here i have two tables namely the rooms and student_hostel.
rooms look like this

```
    id  rm_number  capacity     bed_no             class  hostel    is_vaccant
    40    1           5     1A,1B,1C,1D,1E          27      7          1
    41    2           4     2A,2B,2C,2D             28      7          1
    42    3           3     3A,3B,3C                29      10         1
    43    4           4     4A,4B,4C,4D             30      10         1
    44    5           6     5A,5B,5C,5D,5E,5F       27      7          1
    45    6           7     6A,6B,6C,6D,6E,6F,6G    29      10         1
```

student_hostel looks like this

```
    id    first_name       stud_id    hostel   class    room    bed     status
    175     siraj         WPGH00175     7      28        41      2A     P
    176     nesru         WPGH00176     7      28        41      2B     P
    180     dsf           WPGH00180     7      27        40      1A     G
```

Here is the code that i tried to get all  occupied rooms

the controller looks like this

```
public function beds_occupied($rm)
{
    $data['bed'] = $this->admin_model->ajax_bed($rm)->row();
    $data['beds'] = explode(',',$data['bed']->bed_no);
    $data['bed_no'] = $this->admin_model->get_bed_no($rm)->result();
    foreach ($data['bed_no'] as $row) 
    {

        if (($key = array_search($row->bed, $data['beds'])) !== false) 
        {


            unset($data['beds'][$key]);

            $data['beds'] = array_values($data['beds']);


        }
    }
    return $data['beds'];
}
```

the model looks like this

```
public function ajax_bed($val=Null)
{
    if(isset($val))
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$val);    
    }
    return $this->db->get('rooms'); 
}

public function get_bed_no($id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where('student_hostel',array('room'=>$id));
}
```

the ouput iam getting is all vaccant beds instead of occupied,
the result iam getting is like this.

```
SI no  Rooms    Class          Hostel         Occupied  
 1      1      periyar1       periyar        1B,1C,1D,1E    
 2      2      periyar2       periyar        2C,2D  
 3      3      pamba1         pamba          3A,3B,3C   
 4      4      pamba 2        pamba          4A,4B,4C,4D    
 5      5      periyar1       periyar        5A,5B,5C,5D,5E,5F      
 6      6      pamba1         pamba          6A,6B,6C,6D,6E,6F,6G
```

but  i want to get it like this

```
 SI no  Rooms    Class         Hostel         Occupied  
 1      1      periyar1       periyar        1A 
 2      2      periyar2       periyar        2A,2B  
 3      3      pamba1         pamba          
 4      4      pamba 2        pamba             
 5      5      periyar1       periyar               
 6      6      pamba1         pamba
```

Comment: any body having any idea,the thing is am using unset so the values stored is getting deleted but i want to get the values stored

Comment: Maybe you could create a table Beds, with 3 colums. Bed_no, room_no, student_hostel. With foreign keys to rooms and student_hostel.

Comment: but am getting all vacant beds when i did `unset($data['beds'][$key]);` like this

Comment: i was suggesting you could create one. Your data model is overly complicated this way. Storing multiple values in one column which are referenced to by your `student_hostel` table rows.

Comment: i guess can be found out without that

Comment: is there any code like unset only for that value to be stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unsetting the variables that DO exist. You want to keep the variables that DO exist as they are taken beds. Try this:

```
public function beds_occupied($rm)
{
    $occupied = array();
    $data['bed'] = $this->admin_model->ajax_bed($rm)->row();
    $data['beds'] = explode(',',$data['bed']->bed_no);
    $data['bed_no'] = $this->admin_model->get_bed_no($rm)->result();

    foreach ($data['bed_no'] as $row) 
    {
        $key = array_search($row->bed, $data['beds'];
        if ($key) 
        {
            $occupied[] = $data['beds'][$key]);
        }
    }
    return $occupied;
}
```

Comment: i had given like this already but at that time only 2B is showing rest 2A,1A is not showing